# How To Fix This Error? I want to build app Encrypt and Decrypt file, But Show Error How Can I fix It?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I want to build App for encrypting and decrypting in java, but shows errors, how can I fix it?

I use AES algorithm for Encrypting and I use java, how can I fix it this code?

This is my code at `CryptoException.java`

```java
public class CryptoException extends Exception {
    public CryptoException() {}

    public CryptoException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
        super(message, throwable);
    }
}
```

This is My code at `CryptoUtils.java`

```java
public class CryptoUtils {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";

    public static void encrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
            throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);  

    }

    public static void decrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
            throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        try {
            Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
            inputStream.read(inputBytes);

            byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
                | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException | IOException ex) {
            throw new CryptoException("Error Encrypting/Decrypting file", ex);
        }   
    }
}
```

And This is my `MainApp.java`

```java
public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String key = "Rahasialah";
        File inputFile = new File("D:\\document.txt");
        File encryptedFile = new File("D:\\document.encrypted");
        File decryptedFile = new File("D:\\document.decrypted");

        try {
            CryptoUtils.encrypt(key, inputFile, encryptedFile);
            CryptoUtils.decrypt(key, encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
        } catch (CryptoException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **Messages Error:**

```
Error Encrypting/Decrypting file
   com.fusi24.bms.EncryptdanDecrypt.CryptoException: Error 

Encrypting/Decrypting file
   at com.fusi24.bms.EncryptdanDecrypt.CryptoUtils.doCrypto(CryptoUtils.java:53)
   at com.fusi24.bms.EncryptdanDecrypt.CryptoUtils.encrypt(CryptoUtils.java:23)
   at com.fusi24.bms.EncryptdanDecrypt.App.main(App.java:20)
   Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 10 bytes
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt.init(AESCrypt.java:87)
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.ElectronicCodeBook.init(ElectronicCodeBook.java:94)
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:591)
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:467)
   at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:313)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:863)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1248)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1185)
   at com.fusi24.bms.EncryptdanDecrypt.CryptoUtils.doCrypto(CryptoUtils.java:36)
   ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AES encryption in the following way.

```
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
generator.init(128); // AES key size in number of bits
SecretKey secKey = generator.generateKey();
```

The size should be minimum 128 bits as mentioned above.
Then you have to use the following code to encrypt.

```
Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(someTxtToEncrypt.getBytes());
```